# javascript : toggle scrolling only on document body

Tags: javascript, scroll, toggle, overflow

I need a toggle function for a dialog popup that locks page scroll, but permits the dialog to be scrollable.
I have tried CSS only with, but the code does not work in Safari iOS.

```
body{overflow:hidden; } //does not work in Safari iOS
```

So, i think I may need to use some JS magic for this to work. Any Ideas? thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle a class on the body to stop the scrolling: http://codepen.io/J_Mack/pen/zGMGyM

```
.stop-scrolling {
width: 100vw;/*can also use %*/
height: 100vh;/*can also use %*/
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Read before you use vw/vh: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units